# Regex - Match Last Occurrence

Tags: .net, regex

I have a text file full of names, I want to match them all via Regex.

Each name ends with the following text: fsa fwb fcc, eg:

```
">Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
```

I want to use the following expression to match the names:

```
""">.+?""fsa fwb fcc"
```

AKA match all text from **">** up to **fsa fwb fcc**, I can then parse the excess matched myself.

However as "> occurs throughout the file, it starts matching from much earlier. I have always wondered how to match from the LAST occurance of something, in this case, **">**, up to the end specified.

Comment: In your particular case, [`RegexOptions.RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) should do it.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: And what naomik said. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) is at the top of the related questions. ;)

Comment: This isn't parsing, rather this is pattern matching. Given the requirements I doubt this can be accomplished as easily with an HTML parsing engine as it can be via pattern matching. Also I'm not sure \u0012 is a valid html character.

Comment: Thanks m.buettner, Regex.Options.RightToLeft works perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @neomik, Denomales is correct, this is not a HTML file and the content is static, predictable, and does not vary, so REGEX seems fine for matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

It looks like you're ending string is literally `fsa fwb fcc`, and the beginning of the substring you're interested in starts directly after the last `">` before the end string.

This expression will:

- find the substring between the last `">` and the next `fsa fwb fcc`

`">((?:(?!">).)*)fsa\sfwb\sfcc`

[image]

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/VLNeu4G3um)

**Sample Text**

```
">sometext">A Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
">sometext">B Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
">sometext">C Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
```

Matches Found:

```
[0][0] = ">A Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
[0][1] = A Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"

[1][0] = ">B Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
[1][1] = B Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"

[2][0] = ">C Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
[2][1] = C Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"
```

## Or

If you want to go further and only capture from the last `">` through to the `\u0012` before the `fsa fwb fcc` ... i.e. the actual name and not the markup text, then have a look at this expression

`">((?:(?!">).)*?)\\u0012(?:(?!">).)*fsa\sfwb\sfcc`

[image]

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/pQ2E90BEsL)

**Sample Text**

```
">sometext">A Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
">sometext">B Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
">sometext">C Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
```

**Matches Found**

```
[0][0] = ">A Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
[0][1] = A Dave Smith

[1][0] = ">B Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
[1][1] = B Dave Smith

[2][0] = ">C Dave Smith\u0012\/a>\u0012\/div>\u0012div class=\"fsa fwb fcc
[2][1] = C Dave Smith
```

Comment: This is a really great explanation that is so thorough and works perfectly! I really appreciate that Denomales!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
.+((fsa|fwb|fcc).+)$
```

**+** matches many characters in front.

**((fsa|fwb|fcc)** matches and captures the keywords.

**.+)** matches and captures characters.

**$** matches the end of the line.

**EDIT:-** As suggested by **m.buettner** [RegexOptions.RightToLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) should work for your case.

Comment: [Please add some explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-regular-expression-pattern-really-good-answers) on how this regex works.

Comment: @HamZa:- Updated with explanation. Do let me know if that doesnt work!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately it doesn't work for me, but instead matches the entire file!

Comment: @stanleyhiggins:- Got your point. Updated my answer as well. So that it can be used for future reference also. :)